# How to copy unversioned test resources during release:perform?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

My Question is very similar to "[Maven doesn't copy untracked resources while releasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378708/maven-doesnt-copy-untracked-resources-while-releasing)". I have **test** resources which are not under version control. As testing is part of release:perform that fails without those resources.

How can I tell Maven to copy those unversioned test resources into target/checkout/target/test-classes/. I really would prefer not to skip testing. Those test resource won't come into the public vcs as they have credentials for a webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be many ways to achieve this. One way is with the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) and a profile. The release-plugin sets during `release:perform` the profile `release-plugin`. You simply have add the *maven-resources-plugin* into that profile (or a custom profile which is activated by [`<releaseProfiles>`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#releaseProfiles)).

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/../../src/test/resources/</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

With org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent it's a bit different, as that parent [disables `<useReleaseProfile>`](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-4593) but uses `sonatype-oss-release`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick reply :

You SHOULD not include unversionned resources. This is not Maven philisophy ... indeed you **MUST** not :).

[maven](/questions/tagged/maven) and [maven-release-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-release-plugin) aimed to provide repeatable build. You CANNOT ensure that your build will ever deliver the same result if you rely on unversioned, let say uncontroled, resources.

For later purposes, credentials can be encrypted easily :

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html
- http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-encrypting-passwords/

Comment: So I would store my credentials encrypted in VCS and during build I could decrypt them. Ok, how do other developers work with their credentials?