# Maven Release Plugin and Resources

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

Is it possible to configure the maven release plugin to include unversioned resources in the main jar? I have a static folder under src/main/resources where I output my packaged Javascript file that is ignored by git. I have tried to use a profile and configure the maven resources plugin but with no luck similar to this answer.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515584/how-to-copy-unversioned-test-resources-during-releaseperform)

I also see that the release plugin creates three jars (main jar,source jar, javadoc jar). Is the solution to extract the main and source contents and repackage them?